# .htaccess rewrite if nothing specified

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to modify my .htaccess file to link to three different places, based on the input after the endpoint:

1. "/api" - Link to the API
2. "/ABCD123" - If it's a 7 character
   alphanumeric string, link to a specific page
3. "/" - If nothing specified, or for any other inputs link to the homepage.

---

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/(.*) ./api/index.php [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$ index.php?l=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ everythingelse.php [L]
```

Even though I have the [L] flag specified I always seem to get redirected to the everythingelse.php route, even if I have the 7 character string.

***How can I rewrite to match this correctly?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are looping and executing more than once. `L` flag only breaks current loop but `mod_rewrite` can loop again and execute all the matching rules.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/index.php [R,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$ index.php?l=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule . everythingelse.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why a header("Location:$newURL",  true,  301 ); would append the new URL to the existing one rather than replacing it?

Comment: I don't know what is inside `$newURL` but make sure it has full path that starts with a `/`